# GNU make: time complexity of list accesses

Tags: functional-programming, time-complexity, gnu-make

In the following snippet a given (word)list is inverted:

```
not_null=$(if $(strip $(1)),t,)
invert_list=$(if $(call not_null,$(firstword $(1))),$(call invert_list,$(wordlist 2,1000,$(1))) $(firstword $(1)))
$(info $(call invert_list,1 2 3 4))
```

As you can see, I cheated by giving a guessed upper list limit of 1000 instead of `$(words $(1))` on each recursion, in the hope to stay in O(N) bounds. Is this reasonable in GNU make after all or is the words-function O(1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `words` function in GNU make is O(N) where N is the length of the string.  All make functions parse the string in front of them: they never keep any internal state of the string to try to make future invokations faster.

*EDIT*

I was thinking of something like this (untested):

```
_invert_list = $(if $(strip $(firstword $2)),$(call _invert_list,$1,$(wordlist 2,$1,$2)) $(firstword $2))
invert_list = $(call _invert_list,$(words $1),$1)
$(info $(call invert_list,1 2 3 4))
```

So, the `words` function is only invoked one time and the result is passed as the first argument to the "real" `_invert_list` function.

BTW, you might also take a look at the [GMSL](http://gmsl.sourceforge.net/) which has some cool capabilities, all implemented in standard GNU make.  Not sure about its performance attributes.  It looks like the GMSL reverse is using essentially the same algorithm as your original attempt (calling `words` again at each iteration).

Comment: Is there an accepted way to program such constructs then? Is there something on your webpage (thanks so much for it, BTW)?

Comment: Well, I don't really know what you mean by "such constructs".  There's nothing more advanced than the functions available (unless you want to use Guile integration).  The first thing to ask is, is this really a problem?  The length of strings that make usually works with don't require lots of optimization.  Be careful about using `:=` where possible to avoid duplicate expansion.  If it's really slow (as measured not guessed) and you don't want to/can't use Guile, consider whether using `$(shell ...)` to run a separate program maybe.

Comment: In your example as well you could use a helper function that computed the length of the original list one time, then passed that as the first argument to `invert_list`

Comment: I am trying to compute configuration files in an embedded environment where the user defines tables (or copies them from Excel) e.g. for memory ranges & attributes. These tables are a very-poor-man's config database and I absolutely feel that I am scratching on the limit where make will burn my fingers thoroughly but as the toolchain and environment can't be changed, I have to go that route.

Comment: I will have to $(eval ) that list length, otherwise it would compute the length of the original list at each iteration, correct? $(eval $$(call invert_list2,$$(1),$(words $(2))) ?

Comment: It's fine if it uses the original length, that's just a maximum.  No point in recomputing it every time.  If there aren't that many words then make will just stop parsing; there's no advantage (performance or otherwise) to listing the exactly correct number of words here.  The only reason you even need `words` rather than using _some big value_ (as you did with 1000) is just in case in some environment the number of words exceeds whatever _some big value_ you chose.

Comment: uhm, that's what I was trying to ask :D. How do I precompute the length of the list before I diverge the call from the original function to the one you proposed? To force make to insert the length as an integer verbatim, I need to evaluate `$(words )`, right? Otherwise I would just pass on the text of the call (plus the whole list) to the next iteration. But how to do that when `$(eval)` always has the empty string as result?

Comment: You don't need eval; never mind about it.  My example expands the `words` function only one time, during the `invert_list` function call.  That value is passed to `_invert_list` which just passes the same value to itself recursively.  Remember that `call` expands its arguments BEFORE the user-defined function is invoked, so `$(words $1)` is expanded once, before `_invert_list` is called, and `_invert_list` never sees the `words` function.